# PHP seemingly getting wrong query result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, I built this query in SQLYog, and it returned the results I was looking for. However, when I copy-pasted it into php and used mysqli to run each query / fetch the results, my results were different (namely, one field was null rather than the correct results).

Query:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = ''',
      wp.field_number,
      ''' 
      THEN ',
      IF(lng.value = NULL, 'wp.value', 'lng.value'),
      ' ELSE NULL END) AS ',
      CONCAT(fm.field_name, IF(fm.rank <> 0, fm.rank, ''))
    )
   )INTO @sql
FROM wp_rg_lead_detail wp
JOIN vh_rg_form_map fm
ON fm.field_number = wp.field_number
AND fm.form_id = wp.form_id
LEFT JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail_long lng
ON wp.id = lng.lead_detail_id
WHERE wp.form_id = 1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT lead_id,', @sql, ' FROM wp_rg_lead_detail wp 
LEFT JOIN wp_rg_lead_detail_long lng
ON wp.id = lng.lead_detail_id
WHERE form_id = 1 GROUP BY lead_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

My results are almost exactly the same, the only difference lies in the picture field. Here are some pictures of the difference.

[image: PHP result]
[image: Yog Result]

Comment: is your pictures column is a varchar type or something different?

Comment: The pictures column is a varchar type in the wp_rg_lead_detail table, but a longtext in the wp_rg_lead_detail_long table. I think that's where my problem is; that if statement "IF(lng.value <=> NULL, 'wp.value', 'lng.value')," is causing my problems.

Comment: I think too.. try to fix it see if this is the problem

Comment: @Yair.R That was the problem. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake on my part: I had to add in a section to the where clause to ensure that I was getting a single lead_id (where lead_id = $n). I'm still unsure as to exactly why I was getting different responses for the same query in php and yog, but fixing my query fixed the problem.